# Spring security error ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I tried to config spring security with my project. I use the entity manager for connection to the database. here my configs:

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
     version="2.4">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/content" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

    <form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/content"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>

<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                           users-by-username-query=
                                   "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
                           authorities-by-username-query=
                                   "select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>



 </beans:beans>
```

Spring-datasource.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>project</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

When starting I have error:

```
30-Jul-2015 12:53:11.300 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed     due to previous errors
30-Jul-2015 12:53:11.308 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]     org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.doClose     Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not     initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root     WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jul 30 12:53:11 EET 2015]; root of     context hierarchy
    at     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEve    ntMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:344)
    at     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(Abst    ractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractA    pplicationContext.java:869)
    at     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApp    licationContext.java:836)
    at     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4776)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5390)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1648)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>Itransition</groupId>
<artifactId>iSite</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--Spring Security-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Am I config spring-security correctly? I'm not sure. And what is the matter of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your **web.xml**.

Directly under the:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Add the path to your **Spring-security.xml** and **Spring-datasource.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            classpath:path/to/your/applicationContext.xml
            classpath:path/to/your/Spring-security.xml
            classpath:path/to/your/Spring-datasource.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! But I have new error **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your <security:http> namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration**

Comment: Changing with ** /login access="permitAll" ** doesn't help. I have the same error.

Comment: i solved the problem. Just delete import security xml from applicationcontext config. Seems like it tried to load configs twice

Comment: Thaks a lot for your help! Good luck!